# Margin 0 for ol and put space between li

Tags: css

I try to create a report in html that will be converted to pdf.

My issue is I'm not able to align

1.

with Me, Paul Houde

and
I revoque all... with Previous..

Seem like margin-left have no effect.

[image]

```css
@page {
  size: letter portrait;
}

.new-page {
  page-break-after: always;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Liberation Serif, serif';
}

ol {
  margin-left: 0cm;
}

li {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<p align="center" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0cm; font-weight: bold;font-size:9pt" th:text="#{testament.document.title(${testament.testamentDocument.testamentOwner.owner.firstname}, ${testament.testamentDocument.testamentOwner.owner.lastname})}"></p>

<p style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0cm; font-size:9pt">Me, Paul Houde</p>

<p style="line-height: 100%; margin-left: 1.1cm; margin-bottom: 0cm; font-size:9pt;"><u><b>Previous testament</b></u></p>

<ol>
  <li style="line-height: 100%; font-size: 9pt;">I revoque all...</li>
</ol>
```

an example here
https://jsfiddle.net/2eu903n7/

Comment: Try `ol {margin-left: -40px}`

Comment: `ol, ol li { padding: 0; margin: 0; text-indent: 0; -webkit-padding-start: 0 }` pretty sure there's an answer for the site on this somewhere, it would be the same as a css reset for `ul`

Answer (score 0):

I remember an old trick where you needed to put the font-size to 0 on the parent block (here `<ol>`) and put it back to the one you need afterward on the child item.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand where to put the space

but I solved it with ol.
If you want  to be left aligned, just add `padding-left: 0; list-style-position: inside;`

Code:

```css
@page {
  size: letter portrait;
}

.new-page {
  page-break-after: always;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Liberation Serif, serif';
}

ol {
  padding-left: 0; 
  list-style-position: inside; 
}

li {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<p align="center" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0cm; font-weight: bold;font-size:9pt" th:text="#{testament.document.title(${testament.testamentDocument.testamentOwner.owner.firstname}, ${testament.testamentDocument.testamentOwner.owner.lastname})}"></p>

<p style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0cm; font-size:9pt">Me, Paul Houde</p>

<p style="line-height: 100%; margin-left: 1.1cm; margin-bottom: 0cm; font-size:9pt;"><u><b>Previous testament</b></u></p>

<ol>
  <li style="line-height: 100%; font-size: 9pt;">I revoque all...</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I search to have: 1. Align with Me, Paul Houde.... and I revoque all aligned with Previous testament